# Cannot run downloaded project in visual studio code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I downloaded some project made using HTML, CSS and react on my computer from github and wanted to run it in visual code but i am getting this error as following on picture

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNMWQ.png)

I already updated node and added enviromental variable. How can i run it?

Comment: Can you try to run `npm i -D @vitejs/plugin-reart` or `npm i` to download all packages.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you didnt install the project packages,
try `npm i`